# Android notifications using GCM+PHP or Polling for app

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, polling

I am working on an android app that sends a notification to the clients whenever a new event was added to the server.I find it difficult to choose between various methods of implementing notifications.Should I go for polling(refresh periodically) or GCM ? Is there any other solution ? Since I am new to android app development, I am a bit confused.Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think you should go for GCM instead of polling. Because server load is lowered as devices don't poll every x seconds even if nothing changed. GCM is faster (more responsive) than 5 seconds (current timer).

Comment: Thank you Mustanser Iqbal :)

Comment: Also, polling is much better for the phone in terms of battery use as the radio does not need to be frequently woken up when there are no new updates on the server.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view if you have less than 4kb payload data then you have to use push notification , which decrease the loss of your phone battery..
and if you have multiple client then you may send data a bit of time all of them